# Python threading.stack_size() has no effect

Tags: python, multithreading, networking, stack-size

I am trying to reduce the stack size for a python script in order to produce more threads.
I am setting it like this

```
threading.stack_size(32768)
```

And putting it at the import level, before any threads get started
The problem is that, it has no effect.
With or without it, i can start the exact number of threads.
I am using Python 2.7 x86 on a Windows 7 machine x64, over 2.4GB RAM available.

Any thoughts on why it has no effect ?
I am really looking for a solution, rather than comments on the number of threads I need to spawn.

I suspect it has to do with the .pyc files related to threading, I remember i faced this situation where deleting thoose .pyc files and letting python recompile them on the next run would apply the changes, but I do not know what files to temper with regarding threading.

Would appreciate any help I can get.

P.S. Please do not recommend using Twisted or Asyncore, I know they are better, but I need to make the best of it regarding the current situation, rather than to redesign the entire code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minimum thread stack size on Windows is probably at least 64kB.  [Quoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686774%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
The operating system rounds up the specified size to the nearest multiple of the
system's allocation granularity (typically 64 KB). To retrieve the allocation
granularity of the current system, use the GetSystemInfo function.
```

So trying to set it to 32kB will probably look a lot like trying to set it to 64kB.

Additionally, CPython implements `threading.stack_size` on Windows so that it only controls the *initially committed* stack.  It does not try to control the *reserve memory* for the stack.  From the same location:

```
The reserved memory size represents the total stack allocation in virtual memory.
```

This means that each of your threads uses up the reserve memory size in virtual memory.  You didn't mention how many threads you manage to create before encountering an error but I suspect it's just enough to exhaust *addressable* memory in your process (which is probably a 32 bit process even though you're running it on Windows 7 x86-64 because the CPython build/distribution is x86(-32)).

That is, even though you (your threads) are not using the memory and even though you have more physical memory on the system, Python can't *address* the extra memory with its tiny 32 bit pointers and so new threads beyond the limit you're encountering can't have their reserve memory allocated (because there are no addresses left to assign to it).

If you want to be able to change the per-thread reserved memory then you probably need to call `CreateThread` or `_beginthreadex` differently than CPython calls it.  This probably means need to get CPython changed.

That said, and at the risk of having you yell at me, I seriously doubt you need more than the 1500 threads you can already create.

Comment: That was a mistake yes, but even with 64KB it still has no effect.After doing some reading about this, I found out that the thread module ( from there threading imports other stuff ) is compiled into python directly, and is considered an object, thus making it un-editable. Meaning, even if I edit the stack size, it will have no effect, it will still threat it as 1MB. Am I right about this ? Can you confirm it ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "edit the stack size".  I expanded my initial answer with more information that may be relevant, though.

Comment: I am talking about the default stack size per thread on Windows, which is 1MB as default. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686774(v=vs.85).aspx . So, I am trying to edit that with threading.stack_size() but on windows that is is vain, as the thread.h file that handles that will built-in with Python , thus ignoring my request. I am able to spawn 1500 threads when I have 1600MB of ram free. What I am trying to do is editing the default Win32 stack size which is 1MB. What can I do in this case, if I can't edit it in Windows, but need to run it on Windows?

Comment: My answer talks about two different sizes that relate to the stack size.

Comment: I've chosen it as an answer, seing as it does answer the question posted, but not my problem. I still do not know why I can modify the stack size of each thread.

Comment: To go into gross detail, it's because CPython calls `_beginthreadex` or `CreateThread` without setting the `STACK_SIZE_PARAM_IS_A_RESERVATION` flag.  If it set this flag then you could set (lower) the reserve memory for the thread stack.  Since it doesn't, you can't.  As long as the reserve memory is set to a higher value than the initially committed size, you won't see any memory savings from lowering the initially committed size (roughly, the memory cost of a thread is the larger of the initially committed size and the reserve memory).

Comment: Yes, unfortunatelly, i found that out also, later after posting here. I am messing around with the VS solution file, to edit thread_nt.h but I never understood or liked C. Guess its a dead road for me then . Highly appreciate you took your time to post here, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The OS also has limitation on the number of threads/processes you can spawn. On Linux (Redhat), you can check using ulimit -u. The default is 1024 processes/threads (The kernel treats threads as processes internally--http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/11/linux-process-and-threads/). This, along with other ulimit values, can be set in /etc/security/limits.conf. 
I'm not sure what the equivalent will be for Windows, but this would be a solution for linux users, to be able to spawn more threads/processes.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to get a 64 bit build of python.  Then you wouldn't run into address space limitations.  You would still be limited by physical memory, but that might end up being a less significant limitation.  It would also give you the option of buying more RAM if you had no other options.  The only problem is that as I understand a number of 3rd party C extensions don't support 64-bit on Windows, or at least don't provide 64 bit builds by default.  Any popular 64 bit linux distribution will use 64-bit python by default, so if your software isn't tied to Windows that might be an option as well.  If you are desperate you could run your application in a Linux VM.

I can definitely understand not wanting to rewrite your code using an asynchronous programming style like twisted.  A possibly solution that may be more palatable is to use a userspace green thread system like stackless python or eventlets.  This would require some porting, but considerably less than switching to a reactor based approach.  Again, whether it is suitable or not depends on your application.